# Sending gptp packet as payload of a udp/ip packet

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to send gptp packets through ip network. Since gptp packets only have Ethernet Mac+Phy Headers, I have created an masker node which receives gptp packets from gptp device directly at its input gate and forwards them via udp/ip towards the destination (de-masker).

Destination node (de-masker) receives udp/ip packet, decapsulates them and sends the data (which is originally gptp packet) directly on the output gate which is connected to another gptp device.

The issue is when recieving gptp node gets the gptp packet, it gives following error:

> <!> Implicit data reinterpretation via chunk serialization/deserialization (inet::physicallayer::EthernetPhyHeader -> inet::PppHeader)...

at this line in `Gptp.cc`:

```
const auto& ethMacHeader = packet->peekAt<EthernetMacHeader>(ethPhyHeader->getChunkLength());
```

The packet when received at gptp destination still have ppp/udp/ip headers which shouldve been removed automatically at demasker as packet went through udp/ip modules.

[image]

[image]